# Generate site usage stats/analytics for c# Web API project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, analytics

I've created a basic Web API that returns some data on my internal network.  What I want to do now is to have a simple GUI to present usage for the controller/site.  The aim is to gauge how many times a method in the controller is called.  Despite a quick google search nothing was really jumping out at me, so I wondered what others were using to generate site/usage analytics.

Comment: If you are wanting to log the API calls "permanently", they have to be stateful which means that you will most likely have to log them into a database. You could write a very simple logger class for API usage.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/

Comment: @PeterBons if he is premise based, and hosting the application himself, I dont think that would not work.

Comment: @Hozikimaru why wouldn't it? We use app insights for on-premises hosted web api's.  There is nothing that prevents app insights from working on a non-cloud based website

Comment: @PeterBons maybe I misunderstood. If that is something that can be directly implemented in the code without buying Azure services, that sure would solve the problem, otherwise, if he is not already using Azure, that would be an additional cost?

Comment: "what others were using to generate site/usage analytics."  I would make something myself, output to a separate db with some aggressive 'log rolling' logic, and make a little ui to point at it. App-Insights is good, but your user will likely want something less techy

Comment: @Hozikimaru Not necessary. It is free for up to 1b of data per month and by setting limits you can prevent having to pay.

Comment: @PeterBons understood. It would most likely depend on the application scale, and if it would need more data leverage than that. Otherwise, it would just stop working when the limit is reached.

Comment: Thanks all.  I'll keep the Azure option to hand for another project as we wouldn't be permitted to use it in this instance.  I was leaning towards creating my own solution but thought something may have already existed :o)

Comment: loggly, datadog, app insights, splunk, etc are all great full featured loggers with lots of extras. Some offer hosted and cloud solutions. Also, you can pull request logs directly from IIS or whatever web server you are using.